# Selecting all checkboxes for field reverts to one value

Tags: custom-fields

On Wordpress 4.9.8 and Civi 5.4.0.

It shows multiple values as long as you do not select all of the options. If you select them all, then it reverts back to just one (petitioning in this case) for some reason. Exporting data only shows the one value as well.

[image]

[image]

I tried to reproduce on a demo but it was on 5.0 version. Is this a bug?

Comment: Try again at http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the alphabetized option to sort the field labels creates the error. I was able to replicate this on wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

To solve, I just put the field values in order e.g. 1,2,3 etc. Now it works.

It's a bug, I'll report.